# Display multiple columns in same Histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, data-visualization

### Problem

Hello fellow stackers! I'm new to python viz and would need some helps. Thanks!

I have data that looks similar to following:

| Rank | Class1 | Class2 | Class 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 54 | 94 | 24 |
| 2 | 46 | 38 | 23 |
| 3 | 72 | 56 | 47 |
| 4 | 26 | 47 | 34 |

And want to display the histogram that looks as follow:

- X is the `Rank` column - have to display all numbers, values is incremental and could go up to 100.
- Y is the values of `ClassX` columns (`Class1`, `Class2`, etc).
- The `ClassX` columns will need to displayed next to each other (example below is blue bar might be `Class1`, green may be `Class2`, and another bar for `Class3`).

(Sample histogram only, doens't represent the sample data above)
[image: histo]

How do I achieve this with Seaborn or Matplotlib?

### What I have tried (unsucessfully..)

```py
plt.hist([df.Rank])
plt.show()
```

```py
sns.catplot(data=df, x="Class1", kind="count", height=6, aspect=1.8, facecolor=(0.3,0.3,0.3,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
df.plot.bar(x='Rank')
```

Output (with your sample data):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As 300 bars is a bit tough to fit into one plot, the following approach first creates a column with ranges. Then the data is grouped by these ranges and summed to draw a bar plot. As the default settings leave a rather wide gap between the groups of bars, the bar width can be increased, e.g. to `width=0.9`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Rank': np.arange(1, 101),
                   'Class1': np.random.randint(1, 101, 100),
                   'Class2': np.random.randint(1, 101, 100),
                   'Class3': np.random.randint(1, 101, 100)})
df['Range'] = pd.cut(df['Rank'], bins=np.arange(0, 101, 10))

df.drop('Rank', axis=1).groupby('Range').agg('sum').plot(kind='bar', width=0.9, rot=0, figsize=(15, 4))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

If desired, you can have stacked bars with `... .plot(..., stacked=True)`.

PS: Here is a comparison between the default width and setting `width=0.9` for a plot with 300 bars:

[image: comparing bar widths]

Comment: Thanks @JohanC, this is great, but I will need to display the each value of the Rank.

Comment: Also in that case you cn set the `width=` parameter to avoid too much whitespace.